# Is there a way to use the rewrite module to dynamic redirect based on host header root domain

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a specification from a customer. Given a apache web server with rewrite module find a way to dynamically redirect based on host header root domain.

For example - if request is coming from `www.example1.com` redirect to `example1.customersite.com`

Same thing with multiple level of subdomains (maximum 3) like `my.redirect.to.example2.com` should redirect to `example2.customersite.com`.

Can this be done with rewrite module ?

Comment: What about no subdomain (eg. `https://example1.com`)? And I'm assuming the URL-path should be preserved through the redirect? "if request is **coming from** `www.example1.com`" - Presumably you mean "going to", not "coming from"? Where is rule to be used? In `.htaccess` or server config?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is for any URL-path and this should be preserved through the redirect. So, a URL of the form `subdomain.<example>.com/<url-path>` would be redirected to `<example>.customersite.com/<url-path>`.

You can do something like the following using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:[^.]+\.){1,3}(example)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.customersite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable (accessed using the syntax `%{HTTP_HOST}`) contains the value of the requested `Host` header.

This allows for 1 to 3 subdomains only. The domain apex (no subdomains) or more than 3 will not be redirected.

The `%1` backreference contains the value of the capturing subpattern in the preceding *condition*. In this case, it simply contains the string "example" in order to save repetition.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect.